# conda: proceed in two steps to avoid conflicts

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda

I wrote a conda environment file in order to gather the minimum set of packages needed for setting up my environment. Say that my file is made of packages `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` as deps. When creating the environment through:

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

I get that `D` is conflicting without any additional information (conflicting with `A`, `B`, `C` ? Which is the underlying conflicting library ?). In order to solve the problem, I had to proceed in two steps: 1- create the environment using a modified environment file which just contains `A`, `B` and `C` packages 2- additionally install `D` separately through a `conda install` command. It works.

Is that a normal, at least not so an unusual, behavior I should live with ? Or is that a sign of an unstable environment which may lead to troubles in the future ?

EDIT:
here is my current environment file. The conflicting package is the last commented one.

```
name: jupyterhub

channels:
  - anaconda
  - conda-forge
  - r

dependencies:
  - git
  - python
  - numpy
  - matplotlib
  - h5py
  - scipy
  - pandas
  - scikit-learn
  - sympy
  - notebook
  - jupyterlab
  - jupyterhub
  - oauthenticator 
  - configurable-http-proxy
  - gfortran_linux-64
  - openmpi
  - eigen
  - boost
  - xeus-cling
  - cmake
  - pip
  - libiconv
  - r-essentials
  - r-base
#  - mantid/label/nightly::mantid-framework
```

Comment: Without knowing the specific packages, it's impossible to say or investigate. My hunch would be a sign of an unstable environment though.

Comment: I just added the complete version of my conflicting environment. Quite a lot packages in there.

Answer (score 2):

You're installing a lot of packages, and none of them with a version number. This is unstable by definition. Every time you install from that environment file, you can get a different version of any of those packages, and each new version might change it's prerequisites and their versions.

With that environment file, you cannot even predict which versions of Python and R will be installed.

Comment: You're right there are many packages which without asking for strict version is proned to unstabilities. However setting specific versions for each of them somewhat breaks the philosophy behind a package manager.

Comment: @Eurydice That depends an what you're using it for. At work, I have to fix every version, because I have to get legal approving for shipping things. In your case, I'd suggest to specify versions for the important packages like python, R, numpy, matplotlib, and leave it to the package manager to pick the dependencies.